# Pass pointer to auto_ptr with C++

Tags: c++, auto-ptr

i have a function that does this:

```
static MyClass* MyFunction(myparams)
{
    return new MyClass(myparams)
}
```

and i would be able to call this function inside another one that has the following signature:

```
void MyFunction2(std::auto_ptr<MyClass> myparam)
```

but when I try to do it i have a compiler error:

> Impossible to convert the first param
>   from MyClass * to std::auto_ptr<_Ty>

why? Thank you for any help

**EDIT 1**
As asked the myparams types are normal but there is also a T param because the function is inside a template class

Comment: What is the type of myparams in MyFunction, it is missing in the question.

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of `auto_ptr`?

Comment: @Eric I've added the myparams types.
@Jefromi Yes i understand that auto_ptr let me don't think about pointer destruction and memory deallocation

Comment: But it spares you from that by automatically destroying the object once it goes out of scope - which means that if there were an implicit conversion, you could run into some nasty surprises. It's important to understand *what it does*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::auto_ptr<>` has an explicit constructor, like any other smart pointer. That means that there is no implicit conversion from `T*` to `std::auto_ptr<T>` to prevent from accidentally deleting an object. Hence you need to convert your raw pointed to `std::auto_ptr<>` explicitly:

```
MyFunction2(std::auto_ptr<MyClass>(MyFunction()));
```

It is also a good idea to make your factory functions return a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer, it makes it clear to the reader that the ownership of an object is being transferred to the caller:

```
static std::auto_ptr<MyClass> MyFunction(myparams)
{
    return std::auto_ptr<MyClass>(new MyClass(myparams));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no implicit conversion from a raw pointer to an `auto_ptr`. Just explicitly call it out:

`MyFunction2(std::auto_ptr(MyFunction(params)));`

Note that the allocated memoty will be destroyed after the call to `MyFunction2` because the temporary `auto_ptr` will be gone, deallocating it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to call the MyFunction2 function like this...

```
void f() {
    MyClass* directptr = MyFunction(myparams);
    std::auto_ptr<MyClass> p(directptr);
    MyFunction2(p);
    cout << p.get() << endl; // Prints NULL!
}
```

However, when `MyFunction2` ends the `MyClass` instance will be deleted, and upon returing `p` will be NULL and `directptr` will point to a deleted object.